# Can't add html javascript to seperate .js file (how do I do it)?

Tags: javascript, html

**Problem:**
I need to add the javascript between script tags to seperate .js files.

I also don't know how to link src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js' in the .js file.

**What I've tried:**

Whenever I try to put the content between the tags into a seperate .js file i get errors.

The error messages: https://i.postimg.cc/L8b2X0c4/errormsg.png

**The code:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
             if($(window).scrollTop()){
                $('nav').addClass('black');  

                 }
        else
        {
        $('nav').removeClass('black');  
        }
                 })
</script>
```

**What I want to happen:**

I want the script written in HTML file between script tags to work in seperate .js file. So i can link multiple other scripts to my html.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your attempt at getting it to work, rather than what does work?

Comment: I've fixed the Space and TAB mix error. I should say when I tried the script in HTML it worked as it should. I'm suspecting the problem might be that I can't link the src file "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" in the seperate .js file I'm trying to make.

Edit: Just read Archers reply. I will show my attempt in a moment.

Comment: your code is missing some libraries

Comment: Archer: I've now made a new reply to my question. In the rply i attached a link to an image showing my attempt.  priyanshi srivastava: i suspect that I am.  

I think im missing the src file "code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js".  However I do not know how to link it to my .js file as I can do in HTML:  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that you can't link one Javascript file from another.  Also when you link an external Javascript file there should not be any tags.

Include all the required Javascript files in your html and make sure they're in the order they need to be loaded (jQuery first, in this instance)...

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="yourfile.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

**Javascript** (yourfile.js)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('nav').addClass('black');  
    }
    else {
        $('nav').removeClass('black');  
    }
});
```

As I said, note that there are no script tags in the Javascript file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors seem to be ESLint errors: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef

Try to add for example at the top of your JS file:

```
/* global window */
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(window).on('scroll', function(){

         if($(window).scrollTop()){
                $('nav').addClass('black');  
         }
         else
         {
                $('nav').removeClass('black');  
         }

     })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I seem to have put your names in wrong order of when in time you replied. Oh well :)

---

Hi guys sorry for the delay. I tried all of the replies. And thank you all for them!

**Archers solution worked!**

**Banujan Balendrakumar:** I did, unfortunately same errors.

**Armel:** When adding /* global window */ 2 out of 9 error messages are fixed.

The Error msg that got fixed is: ERROR: 'window' is not defined. [no-undef]

[These are all the error msgs i got before making any changes:https://i.postimg.cc/xdNN5ZMq/whativetried.png]

**Archer:** I tried it. And i now have two scripts that were in my HTML file in two seperate .js files. **So that works.** Thanks :)

However im experiencing a problem. 
*I have two scripts loading in my HTML file/site.
*Whenever I only have one script (out of the two) running (in other words i remove one) the one that is left alone works perfect.
BUT when I run them both it's like the first script is blocking the other from doing it's thing untill it's done. I noticed it works but not all it's features. I will have to look more into that.

**That is another problem for another thread I suppose.**

Cheers.

Comment: This isn't a forum  - you shouldn't post comments as answers (both this and the one you posted earlier should be deleted.)  Put comments under answers if you want to respond to them.